# implementar general tree c++

Tags: c++, funciones

Tengo problemas para implementar el general tree, cree un struct nodo con un char info y un arreglo de punteros llamados hijos y cree un struct llamado raiz que tiene 19 nodos adentro y no necesito que la raiz tenga informacion cree el algoritmo bien (creo), pero cuando llamo a la funcion insertarletra, para que meter la primera letra al arbol me dice que tiene problemas en la forma por como estoy metiendo los datos aqui les dejo el algoritmo para que especificamente el error

```
struct nodo
{
    char dato;
    nodo *hijo[10];
};

struct raiz
{
    nodo *hijo[19];
};

void inserttree(string texto);

nodo *crearnodo(char c);

void insertarletra(raiz *&raiz, char c);

int main()
{
    ifstream archivo;
    char c;
    string texto;
    string n;
    int x,z;
    bool billetevalido = false;
    long long y;
    raiz arbol();

    insertarletra(arbol,c);     
}

nodo *crearnodo(char c)
{
    nodo *nuevo_nodo = new nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = c;
    for(int i=0;i<19;i++)
    {
        nuevo_nodo->hijo[i] = NULL;
    }
    return nuevo_nodo;
}

void insertarletra(raiz *&raiz,char c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        if(raiz->hijo[i]->dato == c)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        if (raiz->hijo[i]->dato != c && raiz->hijo[i]->dato == NULL)
        {
            raiz->hijo[i]->dato == c;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raiz arbol();
```

Eso no crea una variable, eso declara una función. Para creer una variable, tienes que dejar los paréntesis:

```
 raiz arbol;
```

Estás iterando demasiado lejos (¡comportamiento indefinido!):

```
nodo *crearnodo(char c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    //                 ^^
```

`nodo` solo tiene 10 hijos, es `raiz` que tiene 19.

```
void insertarletra(raiz*& raiz, char c)
{
    // ...
    if (raiz->hijo[i]->dato != c && raiz->hijo[i]->dato == NULL)
```

Aqui la primera  comparación está obsoleta, ya has probado en el bucle anterior. Además, `dato` no es un puntero, ¿por qué comparas con `NULL`? ¿Quieres comparar el hijo (`raiz->hijo[i] == NULL`)? ¡Pero entonces tienes que comparar con `NULL` *primero*! Si verdaderamente el hijo está `NULL`, `raiz->hijo[i]->dato` no existe (-> comportamiento indefinido).

```
 if(...)
 {
     raiz->hijo[i]->dato == c;
```

Error doble: primero, el hijo aun está `NULL` (ver arriba) y `==` es una comparación...

No directamente errores, pero eso es C++, así:

```
nodo* crearnodo(char c);
```

Para eso existe el *constructor*:

```
struct nodo
{
    nodo(char c) : dato(c)
    {
        for(...) { ... }
    }
};
```

¿Cómo vas a evitar pérdida de memoria? Si crees un nodo nuevo con `new`, tienes que destruirlo con `delete` también. No se vede que lo has planeado en algun sitio...

Recomendación: ¡Utiliza un `std::vector<nodo>`! Así

- no eres limitado a solo 10 hijos
- no tienes que inicializar punteros con `NULL`
- ya no hay peligro de pérdida de memoria

De manera similar puedes utilizar un `std::vector<nodo>` como raiz, así no necesitas una clase explicita tampoco.